# How to programmatically disable CrashReporting in current Crashlytics (3.14.*) / Firebase (1.10.*) on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'd like to enable and disable Crash Reporting in my current iOS app programmatically. I'm using

- Crashlytics: 3.14.0
- Fabric: 1.10.2
- Firebase (Core / Analytics): 6.9.0

The official Firebase documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/disable-sdk?hl=en tells me to use the following code:

`Crash.sharedInstance().crashCollectionEnabled = false`

But this doesn't work / seems to be outdated as

1. There's no Crash-Class or -Symbol.
2. There's a Crashlytics class, which seems to be the new Crash-class, but it doesn't have a `crashCollectionEnabled` property
3. There seems to be no other API in Crashlytics / Fabric / Firebase to achieve this

I know I could write a custom exception handler and forward received exceptions on demand to Crashlytics, but I don't want to implement such a dirty solution.

Does anybody know a clean way of enabling / disabling Crashlytics in a running iOS app?

Answer (score -1):

for Fabric/Crashlytics: don't call this:

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

Comment: This is the initialization of the Crashlytics. The OP is asking how to switch on/off the crash reporting when the app is already running (after initialization), and most probably he wants to do it in different situations and change it multiple times.